# Dynamically how to change the app invite code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently what I am doing is when the user registers on the app a unique number is getting generated and this code is saved in Firebase and in the invitation text that I am using there is this code to invite other users to join my circle .

```js
Date myDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd  hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
String date = format1.format(myDate);
Random r = new Random();
int n = 100000 + r.nextInt(900000);
String code = String.valueOf(n);
```

On clicking the register button this 'code' is getting saved to firebase.

Below I am showing the invitation activity code

```js
else if (id == R.id.inviteMembers) {

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String code = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("code").getValue(String.class);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi join my Circle to share location.My Circle Code is" + code);
                startActivity(myIntent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Using: "));
                locreference.child("online").setValue("true");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make an expiration period for this code. That is what I need to create a new random number every 5 days.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: You can add time of generated code with code and fetch time with code and match this time with current time if this time is 5 days ago then code is expired and generate new code.